# Danger of mixing numpy matrix and array

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy

The science/engineering application I'm working on has lots of linear algebra matrix multiplications, therefore I use Numpy matrices.  However, there are many functions in python that interchangeably accept matrix or array types.  Nice, no?  Well, not really.  Let me demonstrate the problem with an example:

```
from scipy.linalg import expm
from numpy import matrix

# Setup input variable as matrix
A = matrix([[ 0, -1.0,  0,  0],
            [ 0,  0,  0,  1.0],
            [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
            [ 0,  0,  1.0,  0]])

# Do some computation with that input
B = expm(A)

b1 = B[0:2, 2:4]
b2 = B[2:4, 2:4].T

# Compute and Print the desired output
print "The innocent but wrong answer:"
print b2 * b1

print "The answer I should get:"
print matrix(b2) * matrix(b1)
```

When run you get:

```
The innocent but wrong answer:
[[-0.16666667 -0.5       ]
 [ 0.          1.        ]]
The answer I should get, since I expected everything to still be matrices:
[[ 0.33333333  0.5       ]
 [ 0.5         1.        ]]
```

Any tips or advice on how to avoid this sort of a mix up?  Its really messy to keep wrapping variables in matrix() calls to ensure they still are matrices.  It seems there is no standard in this regard, and so it can lead to bugs that are hard to detect.

Comment: That is why people use Java and other static languages.  The IDE and Compiler will rip your brains out for using a different type (and the IDE will tell you the type)

Comment: If you want the dot product, it's best to use `numpy.dot` instead of relying on a matrix overriding the multiplication operator. [Explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: It is really annoying having to use np.dot especially where you have equations like: A = G*P*G_tran+ M*U*M_tran

Comment: @Mehdi, I agree, however, I'm finding sticking with numpy arrays to be overall a better experience.  Less worry about the return type and it can be annoying to use `squeeze` on matrix to reduce dimensions (e.g. [[1]]).

Comment: At a conference this year they mentioned that numpy.matrix will be depreciated as soon as an alternative sparse representation is adopted.  One more reason to avoid using numpy.matrix.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I tend to use `array` instead of `matrix` in `numpy` for a few reasons:

1. `matrix` is strictly 2D whereas you can have a `numpy` `array` of any dimension.
2. Aside from a few differences, `array` and `matrix` operations are pretty much [interchangeable](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) for a Matlab user.
3. If you use `array` consistently, then you would use `numpy.dot()` (or in Python 3.5 the new `@` binary operator) for matrix multiplication. This will prevent the problem of not sure what `*` actually does in your code. And when you encounter a multiplication error, you can find the problem easier since you are certain of what kind of multiplication you are trying to perform.

So I would suggest you try to stick to `numpy.array`, but also keep in mind the differences between `array` and `matrix`.

Lastly, I found it a joy to work with `numpy/scipy` on [bpython](https://bpython-interpreter.org/). The auto-prompt helps you to learn the properties of the function you are trying to use at a much faster pace than having to consult the `numpy/scipy` doc constantly.

**Edit:**
The difference between `array` vs `matrix` is perhaps best answered here: [**'array' or 'matrix'? Which should I use?**](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935)

Comment: But function readability gets sacrificed.  For example:
F*G*Q*G.T*F.T**2
is so much more readable than any dot(a,b) equivalent.  Would you not agree?  Also if you haven't noticed, I'm a Matlab convert and find it very natural for A * B to be defined as matrix multiplication.

Comment: @user1609675 I think that's a valid point. But since all my previous scientific computing was with Matlab, the syntax differences are pretty much negligible to me because I have to relearn the syntax anyway. It takes a while to get used to `dot()`, and after that I was no longer bothered by it. It became kind of natural, really :)

Comment: @user1609675 Yes I used to do heavy Matlab for machine learning and natural language processing. I think it helped that I decided to relearn every syntax and gradually forget the Matlab way by rewiring the mental model. It takes a while, but imo it's worth it.

Comment: F*G*Q*G.T*F.T**2 ? You could do that cleanly using np.einsum. Though that would mean foregoing using specific optimized matrix multiply libs. But it also means foregoing a lot of temporaries. Could be faster, depending on the details.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn What might that look like?  np.einsum is new to me.

Comment: Not sure I can explain it better than the docs; it evaluates arbitrary tensor products using einstein notation http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html

A product over three rank-two tensors, the equivalent of a chained np.dot operation, would look like: 

np.einsum('ij,jk,kl->il', a,b,c), where the repeated j and k indices are 'contracted' (summed over). It allows you to express a great many matrix ops in an efficient and readable manner; if its more efficient depends on the particulars. Its certainly more flexible though.

Answer (score 6):

Mixing matrices and regular ndarrays can indeed be tricky and often not worth the hassle. I would second other posters and advise you to stick to arrays.

Nevertheless, in your particular example, the problem comes from `expm`. According to the doc, it takes a regular `ndarray` as argument and outputs a ndarray. If you want to transform your output back to `matrix`, you could use:

```
B = matrix(expm(A))
```

or

```
B = expm(A).view(matrix)
```

Now, `B` is a matrix, slices of `B` will be matrices themselves, and your multiplication will work as expected.

So, an advice would be to always check the type of the output of a function.