# Numpy array and matrix multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, multiplication

I am trying to get rid of the for loop and instead do an array-matrix multiplication to decrease the processing time when the `weights` array is very large:

```
import numpy as np
sequence = [np.random.random(10), np.random.random(10), np.random.random(10)]

weights = np.array([[0.1,0.3,0.6],[0.5,0.2,0.3],[0.1,0.8,0.1]])
Cov_matrix = np.matrix(np.cov(sequence))
results = []
for w in weights:
    result = np.matrix(w)*Cov_matrix*np.matrix(w).T
    results.append(result.A)
```

Where:

`Cov_matrix` is a `3x3` matrix 
`weights` is an array of `n` lenght with `n` `1x3` matrices in it.

Is there a way to multiply/map `weights` to `Cov_matrix` and bypass the for loop? I am not very familiar with all the numpy functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to reiterate what's already been said in another answer: the `np.matrix` class has much more disadvantages than advantages these days, and I suggest moving to the use of the `np.array` class alone. Matrix multiplication of arrays can be easily written using the `@` operator, so the notation is in most cases as elegant as for the `matrix` class (and arrays don't have several restrictions that matrices do).

With that out of the way, what you need can be done in terms of a call to [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). We need to contract certain indices of three matrices while keeping one index alone in two matrices. That is, we want to perform `w_{ij} * Cov_{jk} * w.T_{ki}` with a summation over `j`, `k`, giving us an array with `i` indices. The following call to `einsum` will do:

```
res = np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i', weights, Cov_matrix, weights)
```

Note that the above will give you a single 1d array, whereas you originally had a list of arrays with shape `(1,1)`. I suspect the above result will even make more sense. Also, note that I omitted the transpose in the second `weights` argument, and this is why the corresponding summation indices appear as `ik` rather than `ki`. This should be marginally faster.

To prove that the above gives the same result:

```
In [8]: results # original
Out[8]: [array([[0.02803215]]), array([[0.02280609]]), array([[0.0318784]])]

In [9]: res # einsum
Out[9]: array([0.02803215, 0.02280609, 0.0318784 ])
```

Comment: Since the original question used random numbers without a seed, numerical results may (will) vary.

Comment: @Hamid indeed, that's why I posted both the original and the einsum version together using the same set of random data. These two sequences should always contain the same elements, though these will differ from run to run.

Answer (score 1):

The same can be achieved by working with the weights as a matrix and then looking at the diagonal elements of the result.  Namely:

```
np.diag(weights.dot(Cov_matrix).dot(weights.transpose()))
```

which gives:

```
array([0.03553664, 0.02394509, 0.03765553])
```

This does more calculations than necessary (calculates off-diagonals) so maybe someone will suggest a more efficient method.

Note: I'd suggest slowly moving away from `np.matrix` and instead work with `np.array`.  It takes a bit of getting used to not being able to do `A*b` but will pay dividends in the long run.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12024981/2281133) is a related discussion.